# Logstash plugin testing

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

This might be a stupid question, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm trying to write a filter plugin for logstash and started by generating the default "Hello, world!" plugin and going through the basic development process. But I get stuck when running the *rspec* testing process.

These are the steps I followed:

1. Downloaded logstash to my local machine from https://www.elastic.co/downloads/logstash.
2. Ran the `bin/logstash-plugin generate --type filter --name new-plugin --path <path to a new repo I created>`
3. Figured out that I needed JRuby, so I installed *rvm* then ran `rvm install jruby` and `rvm use jruby`.
4. Finally got `bundle install` working.
5. Woops! I still need *rspec* so I `gem install rspec`.
6. Run `bundle exec rspec`, but I get the following result:

   ```
   1) LogStash::Filters::CleanJob Set to Hello World "{"message":"some text"}" when processed
       Got 0 failures and 2 other errors:

       1.1) Failure/Error: expect(subject).to include("message")

           NameError:
               undefined local variable or method `job_1' for #<LogStashHelper::TestPipeline:0x4975dda1>
           # (eval):8:in `<eval>'
           # <my-dir>/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.0.0/gems/logstash-core-5.6.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:75:in `initialize'
           # <my-dir>/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.0.0/gems/logstash-core-5.6.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:165:in `initialize'
           # <my-dir>/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.0.0/gems/logstash-devutils-1.3.6-java/lib/logstash/devutils/rspec/logstash_helpers.rb:134:in \`new_pipeline_from_string'
           # <my-dir>/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.0.0/gems/logstash-devutils-1.3.6-java/lib/logstash/devutils/rspec/logstash_helpers.rb:39:in `block in pipeline'
           # <my-dir>/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.0.0/gems/logstash-devutils-1.3.6-java/lib/logstash/devutils/rspec/logstash_helpers.rb:50:in `block in results'
           # <my-dir>/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.0.0/gems/logstash-devutils-1.3.6-java/lib/logstash/devutils/rspec/logstash_helpers.rb:68:in `block in subject'
           # ./spec/filters/clean-job_spec.rb:16:in `block in (root)'
           # <my-dir>/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.0.0/gems/rspec-wait-0.0.9/lib/rspec/wait.rb:46:in `block in (root)'

       1.2) Failure/Error: Unable to find (eval) to read failed line

           NameError:
               undefined local variable or method `job_1' for #<LogStashHelper::TestPipeline:0x5882b202>
           # (eval):8:in `<eval>'
           # <my-dir>/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.0.0/gems/logstash-core-5.6.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:75:in `initialize'
           # <my-dir>/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.0.0/gems/logstash-core-5.6.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:165:in `initialize'
           # <my-dir>/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.0.0/gems/logstash-devutils-1.3.6-java/lib/logstash/devutils/rspec/logstash_helpers.rb:134:in `new_pipeline_from_string'
           # <my-dir>/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.0.0/gems/logstash-devutils-1.3.6-java/lib/logstash/devutils/rspec/logstash_helpers.rb:39:in `block in pipeline'
           # <my-dir>/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.0.0/gems/logstash-devutils-1.3.6-java/lib/logstash/devutils/rspec/logstash_helpers.rb:65:in `block in sample'
           # <my-dir>/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.0.0/gems/rspec-wait-0.0.9/lib/rspec/wait.rb:46:in `block in (root)'
   ```

What could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you run `bundle exec rake vendor` between step 4 and step 5 in case you have external dependencies? Did you change the the test script of the filer example `example_spec.rb`? Where did you define `job_1`?

Comment: Hi! I actually figured it out! Sorry for not updating, but I believe that plugin names cannot have '-' (hyphen) in their names when autogenerating. My plugin name was 'clean-job' but when I changed it to 'clean_job' it actually worked. My guess is that it's got something to do with the autogenerating code believing the hyphen is a separator or something.

Not sure if I should leave this question up, add my solution as the answer or what to do in order to help future developers.